# How do I preview DreamWeaver sites locally?

Tags: macos, mac, dreamweaver, adobe-cs6

I've got a user that had been editing files directly on the webserver with Dreamweaver CS6 and not using any form of SCM or version control.  I've got him all setup with a local git repository (as well as the ability to push/pull from a "master" repository now.

However, there's one problem that has come up with editing the site locally vs. directly on the server.  With it on the server he can use Chrome to jump out and immediately see what changes really look like.  Locally that doesn't work since Chrome doesn't know the true root (opening a page nested within a couple subdirectories that references a file off another root based directory path will have the references fail).

Does Dreamweaver have a preview function that's intelligent enough to parse the structure as if it was on a real web server?  Or, can Chrome (or any other browser) be setup to do that directly?  Or, are local changes just done in the blind on Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Dreamweaver have a preview function that's intelligent enough to
>   parse the structure as if it was on a real web server?

What Dreamweaver does is allow you to define a testing server and remote (production) server if you take the time to configure a site definition.

You can configure a web server on any local machine (WAMP, MAMP, IIS, Apace, etc) and use that to mimic the live server with a fair degree of confidence and do initial testing and previews.  When you are satisfied, publish to the production server.